ImportError: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - error
I have been experiencing the above error when I'm trying to run a python file in Azure Compute Instance.
Version of Ubuntu is 20.04 and following libffi versions were present already - libffi.so.7, libffi.so, libffi.so.7.1.0
I have created a new environment and have installed python 3.6 in the environment.
I tried to create simlink as suggested here in this thread Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade, Python missing libffi.so.6
I was able to create it successfully but still I'm getting the same error.
What else am i missing out on?
